# questions on python virtual environments

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm on a mac, and I know that any package I install goes to a specific folder in something like /Library/....

Now when I create a virtual environment, will it create a folder structure to store any libs underneath the virtual environment to isolate things?

e.g.

```
/home/user/mypythonvirtenv
/home/user/mypythonvirtenv/python2.6/....
```

Does it re-map the python environmental variables temporarily also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Virtualenv will make you a directory tree that looks like:

```
mypythonvirtualenv/bin
mypythonvirtualenv/include
mypythonvirtualenv/lib
mypythonvirtualenv/lib/python2.6
mypythonvirtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

When you want to use it, you `source` the `activate` script:

```
euclid:~ seth$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
euclid:~ seth$ source /Users/seth/mypythonvirtualenv/bin/activate
(mypythonvirtualenv)euclid:~ seth$ which python
/Users/seth/mypythonvirtualenv/bin/python
```

Other python related stuff (such as `easy_install`) will also work the "right" way.